# startManagingCursor() is deprecated, метод перечеркнут и не работает. Почему?

Tags: java, android

```
    Cursor cursor=db.getCompanyData();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
```

Так же далее не работает метод SimpleCursorAdapter

Answer (score 3):

Этот метод помечен как устаревший(`deprecated`). Используйте `CursorLoader`.
Подробнее о [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html)

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю еще 5 копеек:

`Activity.startManagingCursor()` хоть и *deprecated*, но должен работать. Просто им не рекомендуется пользоваться потому что он выполняется в UI треде и замедляет работу интерфейса. Возможно в последних версиях Android он уже и не работает, но до 19-20 версии он точно работал.

Для `SimpleCursorAdapter` есть [специальный конструктор](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int)), который не *deprecated* (введен в API=11)

Вообще, конечно же надо работать с `CursorLoader`.